# Break function if , if condition doesnt passes

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I got this code

```
 $(function(){
                   $('form.register input[type=text], .search input').ToggleInputValue();
                    $('#next').click(function() {
                        $('form.register input[type=text]').each(function(index) {
                            if(!$(this).hasClass('valid')){
                                $('.note').append('<p>Alla fält har inte blivit korrekt fylda</p>')
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                      $('.register').submit();
                    });
                });
```

the thing is i dont want the form to get submited if there is any field that doesnt have the valid class, i thought return false would do it but it doesnt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ipr101 has mentioned, `return false` does not exit the function. A more efficient method to achieve your results is shown below. Use `:not(.valid)` to check whether there's any input element without class `valid`.

```
 $(function(){
   $('form.register input[type=text], .search input').ToggleInputValue();
    $('#next').click(function() {
        // If there's at least one element without class valid
        if($('form.register input[type=text]:not(.valid)').length > 0) {
           $('.note').append('<p>Alla fält har inte blivit korrekt fylda</p>')
        }
        else { //All elements are valid, submit
           $('.register').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i liked ur solution alot better then mine

Answer (score 3):

`return false;` will only exit the `each` loop, not the entire function. You could set a boolean value to false if you found a field with an invalid class and only submit the form if the value was true.

Comment: so how do i exit the entire function? exit;? break;?
yapp exit; did it :P didnt know javascript had exit ... thought it only had break and return false :P

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('form.register input[type=text], .search input').ToggleInputValue();
        $('#next').click(function() {
            var zero = 0;
            $('form.register input[type=text]').each(function(index) {
                if(!$(this).hasClass('valid')){
                    $('.note').append('<p>Alla fält har inte blivit korrekt fylda</p>')
                    zero++;
                }
            });
            if(0 == zero) {
                $('.register').submit();
            } else {
                // return false; /* if you still need */ 
            }
    });
});
```